# How to detect incoming call status in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way in which we can detect status of incoming call in android like `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING` or `CALL_STATE_IDLE`. If the incoming call is answered then what is its status in TELEPHONY MANAGER API

If the incoming call is missed that is not answered  then what is its status in TELEPHONY MANAGER API. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the state when a call comes in need to create a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to handle the [`ACTION_ANSWER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ANSWER) intent.

You can also add a `BroadcastReceiver` for the [`ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) and watch as the `TelephonyManager` Call State changes.  I'm not entirely sure the behavior of the call status during the call or if missed, but you can pretty quickly experiment with it using `BroadcastReceiver`.

Don't forget to register the receivers in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I'll save you another Google

android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Answer (score 6):

This is what i did

**Manifest File**:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.xxx.xxx.zzz.IncomingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

fields in my **BroadcastReceiver(IncomingCallReceiver)**

```
private static String previousCallingNumber = null;
private static String previousState = null;
private String RINGING = TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING;
private String OFFHOOOK = TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK;
private String IDLE = TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE;

public void onReceive(final Context context,Intent intent) {


    final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String state= null;

    if (extras != null)
    {
        state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    }

    /**
         * This part of the code records that a call was recieved/attended or missed.
         * 
         */
        else if (state!=null &&  state.equals(OFFHOOOK))
        {

            if(previousState!=null)
            {

                        if(previousState.equals(RINGING) && previousCallingNumber!=null)
                        {
                           /**
                             *   received call, the ringing call has been attended. 
                             */
                         String msisdn = MSISDNPreFixHandler.fixMsisdn(previousCallingNumber);


                         Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver", "Incoming Received Call Saved: "+msisdn);


                       }

            }
            /**
             * Else the Incoming Call receiver is triggered when an outgoing call is made.
             * 
             */

        }
        else if (state!=null &&  state.equals(IDLE))
        {

                String incomingNumberForMissedCall = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                String msisdn = MSISDNPreFixHandler.fixMsisdn(incomingNumberForMissedCall);

                if(incomingNumberForMissedCall!=null)
                {                      
                   /**
                     *   missed call, the ringing call has been missed. 
                     */



                     Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver", "Missed Call Saved: "+msisdn);


                }

         }


    /**
     *   Very important to keep the previous state & number in cache , 
     *   as through it we can recognize the received attended call.
     * 
     */

    previousState = state;
    previousCallingNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
}
```